# rails : User button to join / leave a team

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Currently, I get two tables :

```
Users (with a foreign_key : team_id) 
Teams
```

Relationships : one-to-many  (a user can have only 1 team, but a team car have many users)

```
Users :   belongs_to :teams
Teams:     has_many :users

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teams
```

config/routes.rb

```
  get "users/new"
  resources :users
  resources teams do
    member do
      get 'join'
      get 'leave'
    end
  end
 resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
   match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/users', to: 'users#index'

  match '/teams', to: 'teams#index'
end
```

And I try to make a button on the team page (e.g. `myapp/teams/1`) where a user (who call `current_user`) can join or leave this team.

To join a team we just have to update the column `user.team_id` and put on this the id of  the team (to leave a team, the column `user.team_id` need to be empty).

Anyone have an idea to make these two buttons?

Comment: Doesn't RoR's ActiveRecord support relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two actions in your teams controller.

```
def join
  @team = Team.find params[:id]
  current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, @team.id)
  redirect_to @team
end

def leave
  @team = Team.find params[:id]
  current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, nil)
  redirect_to @team
end
```

in routes

```
resources :teams do
  member do
    get 'join'
    get 'leave'
  end
end
```

and links in your show view

```
<%= link_to 'join', join_team_path(@team) %>
<%= link_to 'leave', leave_team_path(@team) %>
```

UPDATE

Note that this code assumes you already have `resources :teams` in your routes and a teams controller respectively. If not, you will need some modification.

UPDATE

You also need `sign_in current_user` if using devise

Comment: Well, I get "No route matches [GET] "/teams/1"" on /teams/1 with this <%= link_to 'join', join_team_path(@team) %>
config/routes.rb => "  resources :users
  resources teams do
    member do
      get 'join'
      get 'leave'
    end
  end
"

Comment: Fixed some typo, and added a notification. It should work. Can you edit your question, and give your current routes.rb? Or only related parts of it?

Comment: Great, with your patch this time this work ! =) Thank !
However, I get a little bit weird problem, I don't understand why when a user join/leave a team then he is redirect to the signin page (controller: sessions, action: new)  and not to the team page (I have copy paste your two actions !).

Comment: this is strange. is updating user cleaning your session? did you solve this?

Comment: Well, the problem is still here . When I update a user with the edit page it's ok (e.g. if i want to change the name). However when I join/leave a team this update clean the session.
The log :
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '6tiKPm-iLjIuf-DFi-iwEQ' LIMIT 1
  Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "team_id" = 1, "remember_token" = 'tOdHqy6Z-ydOkcqFnUfAvw', "updated_at" = '2012-08-03 08:21:23.176172' WHERE "users"."
id" = 101

Comment: It's strange because when the user join/leave a team actually it change the remember_token (see sql log) then this clean the session of the user. (maybe I should make a new thread for this question ?).

Comment: maybe .. can you try something like `sign_in @user, :bypass => true` after updating user (you will need to modify code)? as described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password). Assuming you are using devise